# Is it possible to apply OpenMP?

Tags: c, openmp

I have some code in the following github repo:
https://github.com/2005m/kit/blob/master/src/dup.c

The loop(s) that I would like to parallelise with OpenMP start at line 244:

```
    for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < len_i; ++i) {
      R_xlen_t key = 0;
      for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < len_x; ++j) {
        key ^= HASH(((intptr_t) px[i+j*len_i] & 0xffffffff) ^ 0,K)*97;
      }
      id = HASH(key, K);
      while (h[id]) {
        for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < len_x; ++j) {
          if (px[h[id]-1+j*len_i] != px[i+j*len_i]) {
            goto labelms1;
          }
        }
        pans[i] = 1; goto labelms2;
        labelms1:;
        id++; id %= M;
      }
      h[id] = (int) i + 1;
      pans[i] = 0;
      count++;
      labelms2:;
    }
```

The above code is part of function that identifies duplicated rows in a matrix using a hash function.

So far I have tried to add the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(6) private(j) shared(h, pans) reduction(+:count)
```

When I run the code multiple times, it is massively faster, but sometimes I get the right answer sometimes not. I think I need to figure out how to avoid having 2 threads executing the last lines with h and pans at the same time.

After searching for some time and testing, it looks like the below code works for me.

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4) private(j,id,key) shared(h, pans,px) reduction(+:count)
for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < len_i; ++i) {
      R_xlen_t key = 0;
      for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < len_x; ++j) {
        key ^= HASH(((intptr_t) px[i+j*len_i] & 0xffffffff),K)*97;
      }
      id = HASH(key, K);
      while (h[id]) {
        for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < len_x; ++j) {
          if (px[h[id]-1+j*len_i] != px[i+j*len_i]) {
            goto labelms1;
          }
        }
        pans[i] = 1; goto labelms2;
        labelms1:;
        id++; id %= M;
      }
      #pragma omp critical
      {
        if (h[id] == 0) {
          h[id] = (int) i + 1;
          pans[i] = 0;
          count++;
        } else {
          pans[i] = 0;
        }
      }
      labelms2:;
    }
```

Comment: Parallelizing a code where `goto` instructions are used to exit or continue loops looks challenging. But your main problem could be that all iterations of your outer loop access the same `h` array for reading and writing at locations that are difficult to predict and that could possibly collide. What if, by accident, two iterations run in parallel and compute the same initial `id` value? So, the best candidate for parallelization is probably the first `for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < len_x; ++j)` loop.

Comment: By the way, what is your question, exactly? What did you try up to now? With what results?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: @momo123: you cannot do that, because `h[id]` is being read and written from multiple threads simultaneously, i.e. `while (h[id])` doesn't mean much in that case.

Comment: Yes indeed, h[id] is being read and written by multiple threads at the same time but I think that if I limit just one thread to write in h and pans  at a time that should solve the problem. Question is , is it possible?

Comment: @momo123: it doesn't solve the problem. Imagine having 4 threads which all calculate the same `id` and all pass over the `while (h[id])` loop because `h[id]` is zero. What difference does locking `h[id] = (int)i + 1;` make, when none of these threads has detected a duplicate?

Comment: Yes you are right. Does that mean that this big for loop can't be parallelised? And only the first inner loop can? That would be a shame because when I time this function, most of the time is spent in the while loop.

Comment: @momo123, the hash-table insertion part is not safe to parallelize, so in its current form, your outer loop cannot be parallelized (correctly) by simply adding an `#pragma omp parallel for` directive.  But it would certainly be possible compute the row hashes in parallel, as Groo already suggested, and it would be possible get *one* thread running the insertions in parallel with any number of others computing hashes.  Either of those would require a certain amount of restructuring.

Comment: You should first split the code so that the outer loop and the first inner loop calculate the hashes. `calculate_row_hash` in my answer below is the inner loop. Once you do this, you can parallelize the second part *separately*, but it should then be rewritten so that for each row `i` you check rows `(i+1)` to `len_i` in parallel (and mark duplicates in a separate array).

Comment: @momo123: I have updated my answer with the general idea.

Comment: Thank you @Groo. Ok I see how to parallelise the first inner loop however I am not sure to follow you with regards to the second part. Would you have an example by any chance? Thank you all. Appreciate you help.

Comment: @momo123: I've updated the code, I believe you will need to do all these changes if you want the parallelization to be effective in all cases (few duplicates or lots of duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor the code and split the function into two parts, first to calculate row hashes, and the second which will check for collisions.

Your second problem might be that the hash table uses open addressing. Open addressing doesn't work well when you have lots of collisions because it degrades the hash table performance to linear (`O(N)`, instead of `O(1)`, where `N` is the number of rows). Performance wise, it would be better to rewrite the hash table to use buckets with lists of items, whether with a dynamic array or a linked list (I've used a dynamic array because it's easy to pass it to OpenMP later).

In any case, the part where you calculate hashes should be parallelized:

```
// trivial to parallelize
for (int i = 0; i < len_i; i++)
{
    // calculate_row_hash must be pure/thread safe
    // (note that row_hash is not a hash table, it's merely
    // a precomputed hash value)
    row_hash[i] = calculate_row_hash(px, i);
}
```

Once you have the hashes precalculated, you can build the hash table on a single thread. This part is amortized `O(N)` in complexity **unless the hash table uses open addressing**:

```
// single threaded insert
for (int i = 0; i < len_i; i++)
{
    // not thread-safe
    hash_table_insert(&ht, row_hash(i), i);
}
```

`hash_table_insert` should be a function which inserts the pair `row_hash(i), i` into the hash table, something like (NOTE: this was written out of my head, not tested at all, it's about the concept):

```
// fixed number of buckets for simplicity
typedef struct 
{
    hashbucket_t * buckets[HASH_SIZE];
}
hashtable_t;

typedef struct 
{
    hashentry_t * entries;
    size_t capacity;
    size_t count;
}
hashbucket_t;

typedef struct
{
    int hash;
    int value;
}
hashentry_t;

// quick and dirty chained hashtable, no error checking for malloc/realloc
void hash_table_insert(hashtable_t * ht, int hash, int value) 
{
     int bucket_idx = hash % HASH_SIZE;
     hashbucket_t * bucket = ht->buckets[bucket_idx];
     if (bucket == NULL) // bucket doesn't exist?
     {
          ht->buckets[bucket_idx] = bucket = malloc(sizeof *bucket);
          bucket->count = 0;
          bucket->capacity = 4;
          bucket->entries = malloc(sizeof *bucket->entries * bucket->capacity );
     }
     
     bucket->count++;

     // check if we need to grow the bucket
     if (bucket->count >= bucket->capacity)
     {
         bucket->capacity *= 2;  // grow bucket capacity x2
         bucket->entries = realloc(bucket->entries, 
             sizeof *bucket->entries * bucket->capacity);
     }

     // add entry to the end of the list
     bucket->entries[bucket->count - 1] = { hash, value };
}
```

Once you have the hash-table precalculated, you can search for dupes using something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len_i; i++)
{
    // skip row, if we already checked it
    if (is_duplicate[i])
        continue;

    // find the bucket
    int bucket_idx = row_hash[i] % HASH_SIZE;
    hashbucket_t * bucket = ht->buckets[bucket_idx];
    if (bucket->count == 1) // single hash, certainly not a dupe
        continue;

    // process all entries in parallel
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int j = 0; j < bucket->count; j++)
    {
        hashentry_t * entry = &bucket->entries[j];
       
        int row = entry->value;

        // current row is obviously in this list,
        // that's not a duplicate
        if (row == i || is_duplicate[row])
            continue;

        // if we have too few buckets, this might be a hash collision
        // so double check the actual hash value and skip
        // if it's different
        if (entry->hash != row_hash[i])
            continue;
        
        // at this point, take the slow path
        // (are_rows_equal must be pure/thread safe)
        if (are_rows_equal(i, row))
        {
             is_duplicate[row] = true;
             is_duplicate[i] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `are_rows_equal` does the actual comparison of row items:

```
// Returns true if rows with indices 'row_a' and 'row_b'
// contain exactly the same items.
bool are_rows_equal(int row_a, int row_b)
{
     // check individual row items
     for (int j = 0; j < len_x; ++j)
         if (px[row_a + j*len_i] != px[row_b + j*len_i])
             return false;
     
     // if we're here, rows are equal
     return true;
}
```

If there are many duplicate rows, `are_rows_equal` will be heavily parallelized. If there are few duplicate rows, `bucket->count` will be `1` so the loop will skip most of the iterations. This presumes that you have a good hash function and a large enough hash table.

This is the general idea, it will simply set a flag (`bool is_duplicate[N]`) whenever it finds a duplicate, but you should be able to get more information  it to your needs.

Aside, I doubt that the `R_xlen_t` typedef is needed. And casting the input value for the hash function to `intptr_t` is quite suspicious, to say the least.

Comment: thank you very much for you answer. I have updated my question and found an answer which is working for me. Given your valuable input, I think I will mark your answer as good as well (even if I did not test it.)

Comment: @momo123: if it works, great, but the updated solution is not free from race conditions. Did really get correct results with a matrix where all rows are equal? If you start four threads they will all pass through the `while` loop. If thread 2 finishes first, your `h[id]` in the critical section will have a different value of `(i+1)` than it would have if thread 0 finished first (there are also no guarantees about the way work is partitioned AFAIK, thread 2 will likely get indices in the second half of the range). Try also increasing the number of threads while testing.

Comment: Yes I always get the correct solution even when all rows are equal. I have increase the number of threads to 8. That is the maximum I can do on my machine. I have tried with large matrices and run the function 1000 times. It always gives me the right answer. Now you are right if thread 2 finishes before thread 0 the value of (i+1) is different. The consequence of this is that the rows of the matrix are not ordered anymore which does not bother me. I have tried a few thing to keep the order with schedule and pragma ordered but it did not work.

Comment: although I prefer my solution, I accepted your answer as you were the most helpful. Thank you